# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am making a counter in React and doing something like below in the onclick event :

I have the following code :

```
import React , {Component} from "react";
import Counter from './counter';
class Counters extends  Component{
    state = {
        counters : [
        {id: 1  , value : 10 },
        {id: 2  , value : 20 },
        {id: 3  , value : 30 },
        {id: 4  , value : 40 }
    ],
    }

    handleIncrement=(counter)=>{
         var counters_temp = [...this.state.counters];
        var counters_temp=counters_temp.map((c)=>{
           c.id===counter.id?c.value++ : c;
            return(c);
        });
        this.setState({counters : counters_temp});
    }
      render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {this.state.counters.map((counter)=>
                    <Counter 
                    onIncrement = {this.handleIncrement}
                    counter = {counter}
                    id = {counter.id}
                    >  
                    </Counter>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Counters;
```

The handleIncrement function gives the following error. 
"Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression". If i write a standalone similarhandleIncrement code in a javascript file it works well . 
Further,If  comment out:     `c.id===counter.id?c.value++ : c;` and write :

```
handleIncrement=(counter)=>{
        var counters_temp = [...this.state.counters];
        var counters_temp=counters_temp.map((c)=>{
        //c.id===counter.id?c.value++ : c;
            return(c);
        });
        this.setState({counters : counters_temp});
    }
```

then there is no compilation error but it does not solve my purpose either. 
The child component counter looks like this :

```
import React , {Component} from "react";
class Counter extends Component{
   render(){
       return(
           <div>
              <span class="badge badge-warning">{"Zero"}</span> 
              <button onClick = {()=>this.props.onIncrement(this.props.counter)} type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Increment</button>  

           </div>
       );
   }
}
export default Counter;
```

Why is that so ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
handleIncrement(counter){
     var counters_temp = [...this.state.counters];
    counters_temp=counters_temp.map((c)=>{
       c.value = (c.id === counter.id) ?
        c.value+1 : c.value;
       return (c);
    });
    this.setState({counters : counters_temp});
}
```

Check working eg.
https://jsfiddle.net/0ym96hx1/

Comment: Then how does the following code work fine ? :

`var car_model = [2,4,5,4,9];`
`inCrementCarModel=(car_model)=>{
    var incremented_model = car_model.map((c)=>{
            c===4?c=c+100 :c;
            return (c);
        });
        console.log(incremented_model);
    };
    
inCrementCarModel(car_model); `

Answer (score 0):

your this.state.counters is not having any 'id' as a property in it. I think you should use

```
c.key === counter.key
```

Also show the counter component. Does it passes the id?

Comment: I have edited the code (it still does not work) . And added the counter component as well . Tried your suggestion it did not work either.

Comment: Seeing the counter component, on the button click you are sending the counter as the props back to parent, which means both the sides of assertion should have 'key' property. so "c.key === counter.key" try out this one